# jquery If element id is similar to other element then add class

Tags: jquery, find, element, addclass

I've been racking my brain over this one the past few days and i'm hoping someone can help.
Basically here's what I have...

```
<div id="ORDER/SUB/DD" class="box1">content</div>
<div id="ORDER/GIFT/CC" class="box1">content</div>
<div id="ORDER/SUB/CC" class="box1">content</div>

<div id="ORDER/GIFT/CC/1" class="box2">content</div>
```

All of the `box1` ids are however dynamically created and what i want is to add a new class `chosenOffer` to the `box1` div that's id is in that of the `box2` div.
So it will look like the following...

```
<div id="ORDER/SUB/DD" class="box1">content</div>
<div id="ORDER/GIFT/CC" class="box1 chosenOffer">content</div>
<div id="ORDER/SUB/CC" class="box1">content</div>

<div id="ORDER/GIFT/CC/1" class="box2">content</div>
```

The `box2` div will always have an id matching one of the `box1` divs except with some extra characters (like the slash and number in the example). Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I've been fumbling in the dark to be honest! I know minimal jquery, enough to get me by day to day, but this is a bit beyond me and i'm being hassled at work for things which our system can't currently do, so i have to 'make it look like it can' with styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.box1').each(function(){
  var id = this.id;
  var $match = $('.box2[id*="'+id+'"]');

  if($match.length){
    $(this).addClass('chosenOffer');
    return false; // You can stop checking .box1's now
  }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2pcVa/

Explanation:

We're going through `.each()` of the `.box1`'s and seeing if we can find a `.box2` that contains the ID of the current box.
If a `$match` exists, we add the class to the current `.box1` and `return false;` - which means we don't have to go through the rest of the `.box1`'s because we've already found a match.

We're using the power of attribute selectors in CSS (jQuery uses the same). the `*=` means "contains".
Chris Coyier wrote a good article about them here: http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Comment: That's awesome, thank you so much. I'll test it properly tomorrow (currently should be sleeping and not working!) but it looks perfect. Thanks for the explanation too, really do appreciate it, i've been going through so many other stack overflow questions and jquery tutorials it's driven me mad!

Comment: This works perfectly - although there is a mistype you may want to amend in `$('.box2[id*="'+id+']"')` - just the quotation marks need moving inside the bracket. As i say, i know it's a mistype though :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much like ahren's reply (and improved by its loop exiting after finding the first matching element) but using old school "indexOf" which works fine for me to match the ID:

```
$.each($('.box1'), function() {
  if ($('.box2').attr('id').indexOf(this.id) >= 0) {
    $(this).addClass("chosenOffer");
    return false;
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

This is certainly doable, but I am not sure you are using the easiest/most robust/scaleable approach...

What I would do, is use a new attribute and just set it for the corresponding items.. This makes it much more manageable/editable in the long term.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp